# Return multiple values for antd form item, value pass in array of items

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, antd

I am working in react on a ruby on rails backend using antd. I have an antd form that passes in options from the controller in the backend. The point of this form item is to get an item id number, but I would also like to pass in a couple other attributes that are included in the controller.

The data works for me, so in the code example if I change <Option key={"item_" + o.id} value={o.id}> to <Option key={"item_" + o.id} value={o.attribute2}> I correctly get the other attribute I want. The problem is I want id, attribute2, and attribute3 to all pass in.

Is it possible for an antd form item to have multiple values. In my code example the commented out lines are things I have tried. I tried doing an array like value={o.id, o.attribute2, o.attribute3} and then extracting them with value.attribute2 or value[1], but nothing seems to work.

Or if I can pass in the data as just information like have value={} and then otherdata = {} that would work too, but that didn't seem to work either.

Below is my code,

```
    <Form.Item name="item_id" label={"item"} style={{ marginBottom: "0px" }}>
  <Select style={{width:"200px"}} onChange={(value, attribute2) => {
                              id_variable = value;
                              // id_variable = value[0];
                              // attribute2_variable = value.attribute2;
                              // attribute2_variable = value[1];
                              // attribute2_variable = attribute2
                            }}>
    {options.tanks.map((o) => <Option key={"item_" + o.id} value={o.id}>{o.label}</Option>)}
    {/* {options.tanks.map((o) => <Option key={"item_" + o.id} value={o.id, o.attribute2, o.attribute3} attribute2={o.attribute2}>{o.label}</Option>)} */}
  </Select>
</Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was doing wrong. In case anyone sees this and has a similar problem: I wasn't making value an array correctly.

```
value={o.id, o.attribute2, o.attribute3}
```

should be

```
value={[o.id, o.attribute2, o.attribute3]}
```

Then you can call

```
<Select onChange={(value) => {
                              id_variable = value[0];
                              attribute2_variable = value[1];
                              attribute2_variable = value[2];
```